# Get Original Image Width And Height From A New Image() Object - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, image, createobjecturl

I have an image uploader where I have some PHP checks that happen on the server side. What I want to do is also provide frontend validations for the user, but I am having an issue getting the values to do the maths for the image resolution in megapixels. On the server side I can just use the file's width and height properties and then multiply them.

The problem I have is on the frontend when using a `new Image()` object, when I get the width and height properties it gives me the values of the image file in the container, not the width and height values of the source file / original image.

I thought I could just use the `.src` property and get the size of that instead, but this doesn't work either.

In the code below as you can see the `Image()` object is assigned to a `thumbnailElement` variable.

If you click the `Select Files` button and add an image it will show the thumbnails and log the original file size to the console, but not the original width ?

Note: the updateThumbnail() function is invoked in the HTML

**Codepen Link:** https://codepen.io/thechewy/pen/yLjvqWe

```js
var zone = document.getElementById("zone"),
  selectedImagesContainer = document.getElementById("show-selected-images"),
  fileUploader = document.getElementById("standard-upload-files");

zone.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  // assigns the zone element to the hidden input element so when you click 'select files' it brings up a file picker window
  fileUploader.click();
});

fileUploader.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
  // this function is further down but declared here and shows a thumbnail of the image
  [...fileUploader.files].forEach(updateThumbnail);
});

function updateThumbnail(file) {
  let uploadImageWrapper = document.createElement("figure"), // image wrapper <figure> element
    thumbnailElement = new Image(); // image

  // image thumbnail
  thumbnailElement.classList.add("thumbnail");
  thumbnailElement.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);

  // appending elements
  selectedImagesContainer.append(uploadImageWrapper); // append <figure> element
  uploadImageWrapper.append(thumbnailElement); // append image thumbnail

  console.log("file size is: ", file.size);
  console.log("file width is: ", thumbnailElement.width);
  
} // end of 'updateThumbnail' function
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: arial;
}

form {
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 600px;
}

.select-files {
  padding: 1rem;
  background: red;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#show-selected-images {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 1rem;
  margin-top: 2rem;
}
figure {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<form id="upload-images-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <h1>Upload Your Images</h1>
  <div id="zone">
    <p class="select-files">SELECT FILES</p>
  </div>
  <div class="inner-wrapper">
    <div class="upload-label-wrapper">
      <input id="standard-upload-files" style="display:none;" type="file" name="standard-upload-files[]" multiple>
    </div>
    <button id="submit-images" oninput="updateThumbnail(this.files)">SUBMIT IMAGES</button>
  </div>
  <div id="show-selected-images"></div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the [naturalWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/naturalWidth) property to get actual image width in pixels, also to get that value reliably you should use the [HTMLImageElement.decode()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/decode) method that returns a promise which is resolved once the full-resolution image is fully decoded, like this:

```js
var zone = document.getElementById("zone"),
  selectedImagesContainer = document.getElementById("show-selected-images"),
  fileUploader = document.getElementById("standard-upload-files");

zone.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  // assigns the zone element to the hidden input element so when you click 'select files' it brings up a file picker window
  fileUploader.click();
});

fileUploader.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
  // this function is further down but declared here and shows a thumbnail of the image
  [...fileUploader.files].forEach(updateThumbnail);
});

function updateThumbnail(file) {
  let uploadImageWrapper = document.createElement("figure"), // image wrapper <figure> element
    thumbnailElement = new Image(); // image

  // image thumbnail
  thumbnailElement.classList.add("thumbnail");
  thumbnailElement.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);

  // appending elements
  selectedImagesContainer.append(uploadImageWrapper); // append <figure> element
  uploadImageWrapper.append(thumbnailElement); // append image thumbnail

  console.log("file size is: ", file.size);

  thumbnailElement.decode().then(() => {
    console.log("file width is: ", thumbnailElement.naturalWidth);
  }).catch((encodingError) => {
    // Do something with the error.
  });
  
} // end of 'updateThumbnail' function
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: arial;
}

form {
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 600px;
}

.select-files {
  padding: 1rem;
  background: red;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#show-selected-images {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 1rem;
  margin-top: 2rem;
}
figure {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<form id="upload-images-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <h1>Upload Your Images</h1>
  <div id="zone">
    <p class="select-files">SELECT FILES</p>
  </div>
  <div class="inner-wrapper">
    <div class="upload-label-wrapper">
      <input id="standard-upload-files" style="display:none;" type="file" name="standard-upload-files[]" multiple>
    </div>
    <button id="submit-images" oninput="updateThumbnail(this.files)">SUBMIT IMAGES</button>
  </div>
  <div id="show-selected-images"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Just a note that if they weren't displaying the image, calling `.decode()` could have a negative impact. It will force the browser to, well, decode the image entirely. While they can actually get the size before decoding the image. For instance in Firefox, they do fire the *load*  event without performing a full decoding. On huge images, that can have a sensible impact.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `.width` and `.height` will return the computed width and height of the element when it's visible in the doc.
Since your `<img>` element doesn't have an [`srcset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#attr-srcset) attribute, you can use both its [`naturalWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/naturalWidth) and [`naturalHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/naturalWidth) to get the actual intrinsic size of the loaded image. If you had this `srcset` attribute though, these values could be divided by the `size` multiplier of the loaded source.

If you weren't displaying the image in a thumbnail, an efficient way to get the dimensions of the image would have been to call [`createImageBitmap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/createImageBitmap) either on the `File` object you have directly, and to check the `.width` and `.height` properties of the resolved `ImageBitmap` object.

But since you do show the image, in your case that'd be overkill. Using `.naturalWidth` and `.naturalHeight` (after the image has loaded) is just enough.